# Xamarin.Formsで、パーツにイメージを指定したい

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Xamarin.Formsでイメージを指定したいのですが上手く行かず困っています

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ImageButton.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="test1" />
        <ImageButton Source="Images/btn/Banana.jpg" />
        <Label Text="test2" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

と言う簡単なコードなのですが・・・
Imagesフォルダの下にｺｶﾐを作成してそこにファイルを配置してビルドアクションを「埋め込みリソース」に変更し、そのファイルをボタンとして使用したいだけなのですが・・・

Comment: 取り敢えずこのページ[Xamarin.Forms ImageButton](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/imagebutton)のサンプルを参考に、サブフォルダを使わずに試してみてはどうでしょう？ それで出来るようなら、そこからサブフォルダを作って試してみては？ あとこんな記事 [【Xamarin.Forms】共通部分(PCL)に配置した画像を表示する](https://qiita.com/thzking/items/a0fe98e7b371e13e49b5) があったので、そのイメージも類似の方法で指定出来る/必要があるのかもしれません。

Comment: どうもAndroid、iOSのそれぞれのリソースフォルダの直下に配置するか(AndroidだったらResources/drawable)
共通部分だったら教えていただいた2番目のリンクの方法を使うしか無いようです(なので設計時に四角い枠にどのようにイメージが表示されるのかわからない・・)
他に方法が内容なので設計時は諦めます・・・

Answer (score 1, accepted):

画像表示方法については[こちら](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows)が参考になるかと思います。

埋め込みリソースをXAMLから参照するにはコンバータを用意する必要があるようです。 下記に該当コードを[転載します](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows#embedded-images)

```cs
[ContentProperty (nameof(Source))]
public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
 public string Source { get; set; }

 public object ProvideValue (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
 {
   if (Source == null)
   {
     return null;
   }

   // Do your translation lookup here, using whatever method you require
   var imageSource = ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);

   return imageSource;
 }
}
```

```xml
<Image Source="{local:ImageResource WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg}" />
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。色々名前の付け方を間違えたりして時間かかりましたが上手く行きました。