# Xamarin.Formsでのイメージの貼り付け(csファイル)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

以前[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/71678/xamarin-forms%E3%81%A7-%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84%E3%81%AB%E3%82%A4%E3%83%A1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%92%E6%8C%87%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)で教えて頂いた方法でxamlファイルで自分の好きなイメージを設計時に表示することが出来るようになったのですが
csファイルで動的に作ろうとしたところ詰まってしまいました
上手く行かない例の方で、先日教えて貰ったクラスを使ったり、直接イメージファイルを指定してみたのですが・・・
何かファイルの指定の仕方がまずいのかと思うのですが、どのような記述が必要なのでしょう
imageparts.ImageResourceExtension()
と言うのが、先日教えていただいたソースをそのまま使用しています
namespace はMyApp.imagepartsにしているだけです

上手く行かない例(csファイルに記述)

```
        private void MakePage()
        {
            //gridMainと言うグリッドが既にxamlには貼付ずみ
            ・・・グリッドを色々初期化

            //イメージファイルをリソースとして使用できるようにするクラス
            MyApp.imageparts.ImageResourceExtension a = new imageparts.ImageResourceExtension();
            a.Source = "MyApp.Images.btn.btnPowerOn.png";//★イメージが読めていない
            //a.Source = "{ imageSrcParts: ImageResource MyApp.Images.btn.Off.png}";//★"imageSrcParts:"はxamlが使う名前なので無意味?
            //a.Source = "{ImageResource MyApp.Images.btn.Off.png}";


            for (int i = 0; i < _initVal.xCnt; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < _initVal.yCnt; j++)
                {
                    //ボタンをグリッド上に配置
                    ImageButton image = new ImageButton();

                    image.Source = a.Source;    //★イメージファイルを指定したつもり
                    //image.Source = "ImageResource MyApp.Images.btn.Off.png";
                    //image.Source = "{imageSrcParts: ImageResource MyApp.Images.btn.Off.png}";
                    //image.Source = "{ImageResource MyApp.Images.btn.Off.png}";
                    image.Clicked += Image_Clicked;
                    image.BackgroundColor =Color.Transparent;

                    gridMain.Children.Add(image, i, j); //グリッド上の指定場所にイメージを貼り付け
                }
            }
        }
```

上手く行く例(xamlに記述)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:imageSrcParts="clr-namespace:MyApp.imageparts"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.pageMainButton">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid BackgroundColor="DarkGray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- ONボタン Images\btnフォルダ内のOn.png   -->
            <ImageButton Source="{imageSrcParts:ImageResource MyApp.Images.btn.On.png}" 
                         BackgroundColor="Transparent" x:Name="btnOn"
                         Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お騒がせしました

```
image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("MyApp.Images.btn.On.png");
```

とするだけでした